# SonarQube doesn't see find typescript project unless it's under the netcore project

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have a project with 3 folders (typescript, netcore, xunit) structured this way:
`- src
  |- ClientApp
  |- app
  |- app-tests`

When I run sonarqube scanner for MSBuild then I get reports only for the `app` and `app-tests` projects.
However if I change to:
`- src
  |- app
    |- ClientApp
  |- app-tests`
then sonarqube can find the typescript files and include it in the report.
I have set the `sonar.projectBaseDir` to `src` but it didn't help.

What parameters do I need to set to be able to keep the above structure?

Comment: This is how MSBuild Scanner works. Every folder with `*.csproj` file is a root directory and a starting point for analyse. Everything inside this folder is analysed. Everything outside this folder is ignored.

Comment: Just to be clear, the Scanner for MSBuild only scans files that are referenced by an MSBuild project. By default, projects like netCore projects that use the MSBuild15 project format will automatically include files with certain extensions in and under the project directory (although you can disable this by setting the property _EnableDefaultCompileItems_ to _false_). Projects using the MSBuild14 format do not automatically include files, so the Scanner for MSBuild won't analyse all files in the directory in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from @Peska I decided to try creating an empty/dummy `csproj`. It worked. Not great solution but could help others. Here is how it looks like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="**\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I started off by doing `dotnet new classlib` then adjust following my other project settings.